# XML generation through XML serialization and attribute c# confuse

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

### here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr">
    <OpenShipment ShipmentOption="" ProcessStatus="">
        <ShipTo>
            <CompanyOrName>DARMOT Sp. z o.o</CompanyOrName>
            <Attention>DARMOT Sp. z o.o</Attention>
            <Address1>Ojca Damiana Tynieckiego 46</Address1>
            <Address2></Address2>
            <Address3>DarÂ3owo</Address3>
            <CountryTerritory>PL</CountryTerritory>
            <PostalCode>76-150</PostalCode>
            <CityOrTown>DarÂ3owo</CityOrTown>
            <StateProvinceCounty></StateProvinceCounty>
            <Telephone>943143185</Telephone>
        </ShipTo>
        <ShipmentInformation>
            <ServiceType>UPS Standard</ServiceType>
            <NumberOfPackages>1</NumberOfPackages>
            <DescriptionOfGoods>Remanufactured auto parts</DescriptionOfGoods>
            <BillingOption>PP</BillingOption>
        </ShipmentInformation>
        <Package>
            <PackageType>CP</PackageType>
            <Weight>1</Weight>
            <Reference1>OUR:AWP0021</Reference1>
            <Reference2>Job # 41149</Reference2>
            <DeclaredValue>
                <Amount>999</Amount>
            </DeclaredValue>
        </Package>
    </OpenShipment>
</OpenShipments>
```

which i need to generate from my class through xml serialization in c#.
so please guide me how to write class structure for getting the above xml.

if one look closely my xml then there are few tag with attribute. here it is...

```
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr">
```

so how write the property which will have attribute like above one ShipmentOption="" ProcessStatus="" and also please tell me how to generate xmlns like xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr" with OpenShipments tag. here i have no knowledge how to handle this situation and the path in xml is not fixed...C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr.
it will be different based on condition. so please guide me how to write class for the above xml in detail. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open up a Visual Studio command prompt. Then use the [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) tool to do the job for you:

```
C:\work>xsd.exe test.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\work\test.xsd'.

C:\work>xsd.exe /classes test.xsd
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\work\test.cs'.
```

where `test.xml` is the file you have shown in your post. As you can see this generates `test.cs` which will contain the class you could use to deserialize this XML to:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OpenShipments));
    var openShipments = (OpenShipments)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // TODO: do something with those shipments like for example shipping them :-)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement class (System.Xml.Linq). Example:

```
XElement element = new XElement("OpenShipments");
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("xmlns", @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
element.Add(attribute);
```

If the path is not fixed you can do something like this:

```
string path = "C:\..."; // get your path here
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("xmlns", @"x-schema:" + path);
```